# Syntax error MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `username`= 'jay''

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I have been trying to figure out the right syntax to use but can't seem to figure it out. 
This is part of the code that i think is being affected.

```
private function _check_db($username, $password) {
        global $db;
        $user_row = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM `user`, WHERE `username`= '". $db->escape($username) ."'");

        //general return

        if(is_object($user_row) && md5($user_row->password) == $password)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Remove the ","(comma)

Comment: Remove `,` from this part `user, WHERE`. Nice catch @Yeah, you should have put as answer instead comment.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$user_row = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM `user`, WHERE `username`= '". $db->escape($username) ."'");
```

To

```
$user_row = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username`= '". $db->escape($username) ."'");
```

Comment: @Yeah, i am sorry, i didnt see your answer in the comment when i posted this.

Comment: Thank you! :) can't believe i didn't see it

Comment: @AbhishekSaha No probs :)